# Issue transposing columns with same ID different values not constant

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have a scenario to transpose data values with same ID different values and same value different ID's

Table 1 : BE

| ID | NM | BE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | ABC | E1 |
| G2 | DEF | E2 |
| G3 | GHI | E3 |
| G4 | JKL | E4 |
| G5 | MNO | E5 |

Table 2 : EXF

| ID | NM | BE_ID | EXF_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | ABC | E1 | EXF1 |
| G2 | DEF | E2 | EXF2 |
| G3 | GHI | E3 | EXF3 |
| G4 | JKL | E4 | EXF4 |
| G5 | MNO | E5 | EXF5 |

Table 3 : OXF

| OXF_ID | O_VAL | OEXF_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OXF1 | MC1 | EXF1 |
| OXF2 | MC2 | EXF1 |
| OXF3 | MC3 | EXF3 |
| OXF4 | MC4 | EXF4 |
| OXF5 | MC4 | EXF5 |

**Expected Output :**

| RULE | ID | NM | VAL | DEVIATING_VAL_1 | DEVIATING_ID_1 | DEVIATING_NM_1 | DEVIATING_VAL N | DEVIATING_ID N | DEVIATING_NM N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RULE1 | G1 | ABC | MC1 | MC2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| RULE2 | G4 | JKL | MC4 |  | G5 | MNO |  |  |  |

**Rule 1: Same ID Different Values**

Records with same ID and different values.

As in the expected output, ID G1 has different values MC1 AND MC2 and only such cases are expected. ID G2 has no value and ID G3 has only 1 value which should not come in output

**Rule 2: Same Value Different ID**

Records with same value and different ID
As in the expected output, value MC4 is associated with different ID's G4 and G5.

**What I tried:**

Below is the joining condition for the tables:

```
SELECT BE.ID,BE.NM,OXF.O_VAL
FROM BE
LEFT JOIN EXF
ON BE.BE_ID=EXF.BE_ID
LEFT JOIN OXF
ON EXF.EXF_ID=OXF.OEXF_ID;

/* RULE 1 */
SELECT 'RULE1' AS RULE,BE.ID,BE.NM,OXF.O_VAL AS VAL
FROM BE
LEFT JOIN EXF
ON BE.BE_ID=EXF.BE_ID
LEFT JOIN OXF
ON EXF.EXF_ID=OXF.OEXF_ID
WHERE BE.ID IN (
    SELECT BE.ID
    FROM BE
LEFT JOIN EXF
ON BE.BE_ID=EXF.BE_ID
LEFT JOIN OXF
ON EXF.EXF_ID=OXF.OEXF_ID
    GROUP BY BE.ID
    HAVING COUNT(distinct OXF.O_VAL) > 1
)
UNION
/* RULE 2 */
SELECT 'RULE2' AS RULE,BE.ID,BE.NM,OXF.O_VAL AS VAL
FROM BE
LEFT JOIN EXF
ON BE.BE_ID=EXF.BE_ID
LEFT JOIN OXF
ON EXF.EXF_ID=OXF.OEXF_ID
WHERE OXF.O_VAL IN (
    SELECT OXF.O_VAL
    FROM BE
LEFT JOIN EXF
ON BE.BE_ID=EXF.BE_ID
LEFT JOIN OXF
ON EXF.EXF_ID=OXF.OEXF_ID
    GROUP BY OXF.O_VAL
    HAVING COUNT(distinct BE.ID) > 1
);
```

In both cases, I get records with same ID different values and vice versa but how do I transpose them when I don't know how many columns I might need too. Could some one please help me with it?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cacf4/15

Comment: What logic determines which data is "deviating"? Solution might involve calculating a row number for each group and using that value as column header in a PIVOT (CROSSTAB) query. Problem is you want to transpose 3 fields. I use MSAccess and don't know if SQLServer stored procedure can handle. Maybe following will give you ideas for SQLServer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues.

Comment: [dup on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287402/sql-issue-transposing-columns-with-same-id-different-values-not-constant)