# Microsoft Access new columns for data based on matching values

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns, ms-access-2016

I asked this question a few months back but now I'm working out of MS-Access and I'm unsure how to proceed. I have a query that lists the bldid, unitid, and resident id in separate columns. I'd like to modify the query output in Microsoft Access so that each resident that shares a building / unit shows as a new column on the same row as shown below. But since I'm limited to MS Access I can't seem to use with, cte, or rownumber. I'm at a loss as to how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Query1

| BldID | UnitID | ResidentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201 | John Smith |
| 1 | 201 | Jane Doe |
| 1 | 202 | Daniel Jones |
| 1 | 202 | Mark Garcia |
| 2 | 201 | Maria Lee |
| 2 | 201 | Paul Williams |
| 2 | 201 | Mike Jones |

Desired Output from edited Query

| BldID | UnitID | Res1 | Res2 | Res3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201 | John Smith | Jane Doe |  |
| 1 | 202 | Daniel Jones | Mark Garcia |  |
| 2 | 201 | Maria Lee | Paul Williams | Mike Jones |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot Query in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Crosstab Query

```sql
TRANSFORM Max(Resident.ResidentID) AS MaxOfResidentID
SELECT Resident.BldID, Resident.UnitID
FROM Resident
GROUP BY Resident.BldID, Resident.UnitID
ORDER BY Resident.BldID, Resident.UnitID
PIVOT "Res" & (DCount("*",
               "Resident",
               "BldID=" & [BldID] & " AND UnitID=" & [UnitID] &
               " AND ResidentID<'" & [ResidentID] & "'") + 1);
```

If you need a constant number of columns (e.g. if you want to create an Access report), then you can add an `In` clause to this query (before the `;`):

```sql
In ("Res1","Res2","Res3","Res4","Res5","Res6")
```

This always creates 6 columns with the same names.

The difficulty is to get the row number per BldID/UnitID group. This is achieved by

```vb
DCount(1,
       "Resident",
       "BldID=" & [BldID] & 
       " AND UnitID=" & [UnitID] &
       " AND ResidentID<'" & [ResidentID] & "'") + 1
```

where `Resident` is the name of your table or query. It counts residents having the same `BldID` and `UnitID` but having a smaller `ResidentID`. Adding 1 to this count yields the row number starting at 1. Then the string `"Res"` is prepended to build the column name.

Note that the residents are listed in alphabetical order form left to right.

Comment: Thanks to your detailed example. I was able to get this working with only a few issues. I do have a question, if either BldID or UnitID were to be a short text field instead of a number field how would I adjust Dcount to handle that?

Comment: In SQL strings are enclosed in single quotes. You would have to enclose both of them in single quotes as I did for `ResidentID` in the `DCount` function. `"BldID='" & [BldID] & "' AND UnitID='" & [UnitID] & "' AND ResidentID<'" & [ResidentID] & "'"`