# How can I populate columns in a pivot query in an Access query as first in?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a access database (latest version) that holds all of our logs.  One of the child tables has two columns, "job" and "Options".  The "job" field is linked to a one-to-many larger primary table.  I am looking to make a query that would allow me to see this tables "job" on one row with all of the "options" for that job. I have looked at crosstabs and pivots but the "Options" data is always forced in the same column.  I am wanting the data of the "options" column to fill in the first spot on each row without caring about that columns header.  My table has 600+ "jobs" and each job could have 2 to 50 same or different "options" tags.  [image: sample of table vs query output]

Comment: Need to calculate a sequence number for each job group and use that calculated value as the column headers. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access

Comment: Alternative uses VBA to concatenate options into a single string for each job. Search "Allen Browne ConcatRelated function".

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I was able to make this work for me.  Thanks again.