# How to create a report in ms access with only completed tasks

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

[MS Access table proforma and report proforma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51dln.jpg)

I tried to generate a report in ms access by selecting all fields from the table but, i want to restrict the report that to be show only records and column name and non-empty value only

Date           Unit Name   Tasks completed
01-10-2022         A            1- True
02-10-2022         B            3- True, 8-True
03-10-2022         C            5- True
---- etc....

Comment: I think you'll need to simulate UNPIVOT, by a union on something like `select date,key,col1` for each of the columns

Comment: Can you please elabirate

Comment: select date,key,col1 union all select date,key,col2 union al select date,key,col3 etc.etc   https://www.google.com/search?q=simuate+unpivot+in+access&oq=simuate+unpivot+in+access&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l2j33i22i29i30.8020j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Either normalize schema or live with 'workaround' solutions. Dynamically removing columns for each record is not possible. Column is either in RecordSource or it isn't. A workaround is VBA procedure writing data to a 'temp' table to present the desired output.

Comment: A UNION query could certainly rearrange to more normalized structure but that would mean multiple rows for each date/unit.

Comment: The UNION query could be source for a CROSSTAB PIVOT using DCount() as demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access

Comment: However, building a stable report based on CROSSTAB is difficult due to dynamic field headers of CROSSTAB.