Access 2016 - Change multiple rows of PC numbers into columns against UserID
I am trying to sort a list of Users and the PCs they use.
Currently it is in the format:



User
PC




AA1
123


AA1
124


AA1
125


BB1
126


CC1
127


CC1
128



But I want it more like:



User
PC1
PC2
PC3




AA1
123
124
125


BB1
126
-
-


CC1
127
128
-



Need something that can run over hundreds of rows so prefer to keep it all in Access instead of exporting to Excel and using Pivot tables

Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access
